# linux- windows cross c++ application

Tags: c++, windows, linux, typedef

I'm developing an application which has to run on Linux and Windows.
I have an object called obj which I want to use in the code and it has different behavior on Linux and Windows. so I inherit aaa and called WindowsObj for Windows object and LinuxObj for Linux object.

My question is: How to use this object in the code? what do I have to write that it will run both for Linux and Windows?

For swiching types I use typedef like:

```
typedef uint32_t       DWORD;
```

but what do I have to use for objects?
I want to write this code:

```
tr1::shared_ptr<WindowsObj> windowsobj (new WindowsObj(parameter));
tr1::shared_ptr<LinuxObj> linuxobj (new LinuxObj(parameter));
```

Any idea?

Comment: You do not have an object aaa; you have a class aaa. You cannot inherit from an object. An object is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing :)

```
class _object
{
};

class WindowsObject : public _object
{
};

class LinuxObject  public _object
{
};

#if defined(WIN32)
typedef WindowsObject Object;
#else
typedef LinuxObject Object;
#endif

Object myObject;
```

EDIT: Naturally, the interface that WindowsObject and LinuxObject expose must be the same.  In this example, `_object` would be an abstract base-class that defined the interface, and LinuxObject and WindowsObject would then implement this interface, hiding away the platform-specific stuff in their implementation files.

**Sample**

_object.h

```
class _object
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
}; // eo class _object
```

WindowsObject.h

```
#include "_object.h"

class WindowsObject : public _object
{ 
public:
    virtual void doSomething();
}; // eo class WindowsObject
```

WindowsObject.cpp

```
#if defined(WIN32)
#include <windows.h>

void WindowsObject::doSomething()
{
    // do something totally reliant on windows here
}; // eo doSomething
#endif
```

Then you would do the same for `LinuxObject.h` and `LinuxObject.cpp`, the latter having completely different preprocessor instructions.  e.g, `#if defined(UNIX)` or some such flavor.  Note the `WIN32` guards around the implementation.  Then you'd have some core header file you'd use:

```
#if defined(WIN32)
#include "WindowsObject.h"
typedef WindowsObject Object;
#else
#include "LinuxObject.h"
typedef LinuxObject Object;
#endif
```

Now, in your program

```
Object a;
a.doSomething();
```

It's worth noting that, if it's just the odd line of code that differs in your complex object (like a init call at initialisation, destruction) you might be better off with a single platform-agnostic Object and put guards in the implementation.  This solution makes more sense when there are huge differences.

Comment: Mmm, this way both the codebase would be compiled and linked. I would prefer a single "platform agnostic" object, with the #ifdef inside of it, only for the platform dependent parts.

Comment: @Wizard - then you could around the class declarations/definitions with typedef-s, too. But you should compile on both platforms - two different versions.

Comment: @Wizard, I guess it depends on how different they are.  The single "platform-agnostic" approach works if there are a few "here and there" differences, but if it is vastly different, it is far more readable to have two implementations that are not cluttered with `#if defined` every couple of lines.  It really depends on the difference.

Comment: This seem like a neat way to do it, but the problem of all the code being compiled either way is kind of bad in my opinion

Comment: Completely agree with Moo-Juice

Comment: thank you for the sample.in my code I have aaaw and aaal. but when I use "new aaa" there is an error:"cannot alocate an object of abstract type "aaa"

Comment: You do a new on the  concrete  type that you typedef

Comment: I didn't understand what do I have to write. see my edited question for the line I want to write.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use conditional compilation for this, e.g.

```
#ifdef WIN32
// windows-specific code
#else
// non-windows
#endif
```

Comment: I assume this would be fine if you wrote the same class name for the both the win32 and *nix section of this `#ifdef` thing.

Comment: yes. As others have commented, the best way to do it depends on how much difference there is between the two implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a cross platform framework, like GTK+ or wxWidgets, so that you hadn't to reinvent the wheel...

Then, you should have the least possible platform depended code, and possibly well deep-inside your classes. There you can use `#ifdef` to conditionally include code for Windows or for Unix.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the same header file with two different implementations in two different .cpp files; the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl) makes this possible even if the two implementations require completely different data members. You simply compile and link one source when compiling for Windows and a different one when compiling for Linux.

One area that I've found this useful is for email interfaces. The two OS have completely different methods for sending emails.

Answer (score -1):

Hi if you can use c++, use boost and size_t type its better way.

Comment: Read the question. the `uint` and `DWORD` is being used as an example, he is asking how to achieve a similar thing for is own complex classes.